# DropDownList has a SelectedValue that is Invalid in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, .net-4.0

I have a DropDownList in a GridView within some of its columns' EditItemTemplate. Here is an example of one entry:

```
<asp:TemplateField meta:resourcekey="server" SortExpression="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("server") %>' ID="server" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList Width="100%"
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("server") %>'
            OnInit="server_Init" ID="server" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The problem is that some values contained for these fields will become 'inactive' over time and will not appear as selectable within the DropDownList. When opening an older order and editing a row where this field has an invalid value, I would like the DropDownList to show no value. Instead, it will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception stating an invalid entry.

What is the cleanest solution? I would really prefer not to work in the codebehind of the GridView to catch this error for each DropDownList as they are numerous. Is there any way I can catch this error, have it default to empty, and have it work for all DropDownLists across the GridView?

Thanks.

**Note:** the DropDownList is being populated in its OnInit method.

Comment: Hi do you still need help with this? let me know

Answer (score 0):

> I would really prefer not to work in the codebehind of the GridView to catch this error for each DropDownList as they are numerous.

Well I'm sorry but you have to code your way out of this, I don't see how you can catch error without coding:

**ASP markup**

```
<asp:TemplateField meta:resourcekey="server" SortExpression="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("server") %>' ID="server" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="server" runat="server"
                          Width="100%">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == GridView1.EditIndex)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("server");
            ddl.OnInit = "server_Init";                    
            try
            {
                ddl.SelectedValue = server;
                ddl.DataBind();
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                ddl.SelectedValue = "Order Not Available";
                ddl.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```